# An object or column name is missing or empty

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2005, t-sql

I am getting the following error

An object or column name is missing or empty. For SELECT INTO statements, verify each column has a name. For other statements, look for empty alias names. Aliases defined as "" or [] are not allowed. Add a name or single space as the alias name.

for the query show below:

```
CREATE         PROC [dbo].[Sp_Table1] @ctlg_ipt_event_id int
AS
SET NOCOUNT ON

DECLARE @current_status NCHAR(1), @ready_status_code NCHAR(1)
DECLARE @current_action NCHAR(1), @ready_action_code NCHAR(1), @done_action_code NCHAR(1)
DECLARE @pst_user_id int


SELECT @current_status =  status_code 
      ,@current_action =  action_code
      ,@pst_user_id = last_mod_user_id
  FROM merch_ctlg_ipt_event 
 WHERE ctlg_ipt_event_id = @ctlg_ipt_event_id

Select @ready_status_code = 'o'
, @ready_action_code = 'a'
, @done_action_code = 'b'

IF @current_status <> @ready_status_code OR @current_action <> @ready_action_code
BEGIN
RETURN 
END


BEGIN TRAN

declare @rows int
  ,@err int
  ,@i int
  ,@name nvarchar(50) --COLLATE SQL_AltDiction_Pref_CP850_CI_AS 
          ,@resolved_View_Name_category_id int
          ,@xref_value int
          ,@availability_start_date datetime
          ,@availability_end_date datetime
          ,@status_code int
          ,@last_mod_user_id int
          ,@CT datetime
          ,@supplier_id int
          ,@View_Name_id int
   select @i = 1
         ,@CT = current_timestamp

Select  Distinct mc.name,
   mc.resolved_View_Name_category_id,
  mc.xref_value,
  mc.availability_start_date,
  mc.availability_end_date,
  mc.status_code,
  CASE WHEN mc.last_mod_user_id = 42
       THEN @pst_user_id 
       ELSE mc.last_mod_user_id 
       END as last_mod_user_id,
  CURRENT_tsp
  ,IDENTITY(int,1,1) as rn
  ,si.supplier_id 
  ,si.View_Name_id 
 into #temp 
FROM View_Name AS si
JOIN merch_ctlg_ipt_View_Name AS mc
  ON  mc.supplier_id = si.supplier_id
  AND mc.resolved_View_Name_id = si.View_Name_id
  AND mc.cat_imp_event_id = @ctlg_ipt_event_id
  AND mc.accept_flag = 'y'
WHERE si.shipper_flag = 'n'
select @rows=@@ROWCOUNT,@err=@@error
if @rows > 0 and @err=0 
Begin 

   While @i <=@rows
         begin
            SElect @name = name,
                   @resolved_View_Name_category_id = resolved_View_Name_category_id,
                   @xref_value = xref_value,
                   @availability_start_date = availability_start_date,
                   @availability_end_date = availability_end_date,
                   @status_code = mc.status_code,
                   @last_mod_user_id =last_mod_user_id ,
                  ,@i=@i+1
                  ,@supplier_id=supplier_id
                  ,@View_Name_id=View_Name_id
              from #temp
             Where rn=@i
            UPDATE View_Name
               SET name = @name,
                   View_Name_category_id = @resolved_View_Name_category_id,
                   xref_value = @xref_value,
                   availability_start_date = @availability_start_date,
                   availability_end_date = @availability_end_date,
                   status_code = @status_code,
                   last_mod_user_id = @last_mod_user_id ,
                   last_mod_timestamp = @CT
             Where @sup_id = supplier_id
               AND @View_Name_id = View_Name_id
               AND shipper_flag = 'n'
             IF @@ERROR > 0
             BEGIN
               ROLLBACK TRAN
               RETURN
               END
          End
 End 


UPDATE
merch_ctlg_ipt_event
SET action_code = @done_action_code,
  last_mod_timestamp = @CT
WHERE ctlg_ipt_event_id = @ctlg_ipt_event_id

IF @@ERROR > 0
BEGIN
ROLLBACK TRAN
RETURN
END


COMMIT TRAN
Return
go
```

Could you please help ?

Comment: Impossible to tell, without knowing the structures of all tables and views referenced in the query. Look at all of them and see if any of the columns references in the query is missing.

Comment: +1 Simply for the `IDENTITY(int,1,1)` I'd never seen that before.

Answer (score 6):

You have 2 commas in a row here

```
 @last_mod_user_id =last_mod_user_id ,
                  ,@i=@i+1
```

Also probably not relevant to the error message but you have a line

```
         Where @sup_id = supplier_id
```

but the declared variable is `@supplier_id`